# Wordwrapping existing text

Tags: linux, vim

I've been googling around and discovered that I can word wrap in `vim` by first `:set wrap linebreak nolist`, then `set tw=80`. Text I now type will be word-wrapped.

If I want to word-wrap the text already in the document, I need to highlight everything and press `gq`. This isn't practical if I want to word-wrap an already large text document for easier reading.

Is there a way I can word-wrap the existing text without having to first select every line visually?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to format the whole file would be to run:

```
gggqG
```

The `gg` moves to the start of the file and the `gqG` formats all the lines
between the current position and the last line of the file (`G`).

However, this can result in some lines (not separated by an empty line) being
treated as belonging to the same paragraph and being *joined* to each other,
i.e., the line breaks are removed.

If this happens, you can use the `gww` command which formats *only the current
line*. To apply this to every line in your file, you can run the
following in command mode:

```
:%normal gww
```

Answer (score 2):

Anthony's answer is straight to the point. However, you can also use `ggvG` to highlight the entire file. The `gg` moves at the beginning and `vG` highlights until the end of the file.